Rails app not updating page when in responsive mode
I have an app built using Ruby 3.3, Rails 7 with import map and dart-sass for my asset-pipeline, the application uses bootstrap for css and coreui\coreui-admin as FE template.
Saying that my error is the following:
When the application is in responsive mode or running on mobile browser the first updates runs well I can add a new data or edit an existing one, but after navigate between different controllers the updates for new\edit stop to work.
What is more strange on that is after the update render stops if I navigate for a different controller and press the button new/edit the request is done, but the update is not applied and in the console log doesn't display any error, but if I keep clicking in the button the subsequent requests aren't done.
Below the code of my base index page:
  <% unless content_for?(:navbar) %>
  <ul class="nav justify-content-end mb-3 mt-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <%= link_to url_for(controller: controller_name, action: :new), class: "btn btn-primary rounded-pill" do %>
        <span class="cil-plus">
        </span>
        <%= t 'backoffice.button_new' %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <%= yield :navbar %>
<% end %>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table border mb-0">
    <thead class="fw-semibold text-nowrap">
      <tr class="align-middle">
        <%= yield :thead %>
        <% if @can_read_and_write %>
          <th class="bg-body-secondary">
          </th>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="align-middle">
      <% if @objects && @objects.any? %>
        <% @objects.each do |obj| %>
          <tr class="align-middle">
            <fieldset>
              <%= yield obj %>
            </fieldset>
            <% if @can_read_and_write %>
              <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-transparent p-0" type="button" data-coreui-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <svg class="icon">
                      <use xlink:href="<%= asset_path "/assets/coreui/icons-2/sprites/free.svg" %>#cil-options"></use>
                    </svg>
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                    <%= link_to t("admin.edit"), url_for(controller: controller_name, action: :edit, id: obj.id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                    <% unless @current_user.id == obj.id %>
                      <%= link_to t("admin.delete"), url_for(controller: controller_name, action: :destroy, id: obj.id), data: { "turbo-method": :delete }, class: "dropdown-item text-danger" %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            <% else %>
              <td></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="pag-bar mt-3 pt-3">
    <% if @pagy %>
      <%== pagy_bootstrap_nav(@pagy) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

Also if I change back to full view everything works well, but only in a pc not in mobile browsers.
After unload Turbo the updates started to work, I'll share my application.js to see if I misconfigured it.
application.js:
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

import "chart.js";
import "@kurkle/color";

import "@coreui/coreui";
import "@coreui/icons";
import "@coreui/utils";
import "@coreui/chartjs";
import "@coreui/admin";

document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
  reloadCoreUiTools();

  const header = document.querySelector("header");
  document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (header) {
      header.classList.toggle(
        "shadow-sm",
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0
      );
    }
  });
});

function reloadCoreUiTools() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".toast")).forEach((toastNode) =>
    coreui.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastNode)
  );

  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-coreui-toggle="tooltip"]')
  ).forEach((toolTipNode) => coreui.Tooltip.getOrCreateInstance(toolTipNode));

  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-coreui-toggle="popover"]')
  ).forEach((popoverNode) => coreui.Popover.getOrCreateInstance(popoverNode));
}


Finally found the issue, was the way the coreui.Sidebar was been called in my stimulus controller, I've been handling with toggle and unfold of the sidebar using the controller, but in some way the Js was breaking something that make the usage of Turbo useless, so I've changed to use the native data selectors of coreui and puff, everything started to work fine.
I still don't understand why no error has been displayed or why the coreui.sidebar caused this weird behavior on Turbo.
But I hope if someone face this same issue could use this answer to go through it.
